# create a new file structure within an old while moving old within new

Tags: powershell, batch-file, directory

So my title is a little confusing, but basically I have been handed the task of writing a script (I’m not a big scripter) to reorganize our customer files.

Currently there are a number of sub-directory’s in our customers directory each sub directory contains the customer name. Within the Customer name directory is a bunch of random files and additional subdirectory.

I need to move the contents of the Customer directory into a folder with in the same directory named "needs organized"

After this has been done I need to create the following file structure in addition on the customer directory.

```
       -Estimates
       -Projects
       -Contracts
```

**Below is what the File tree looks like now**

```
Customers
    -Customer A
        -“random file 1”
        -“random directory with files”  
     -Customer B
        -“random file 1”
        -“random directory with files”
```

**Below is what the file tree should look like when done**

```
Customers
    -Customer A
        -Needs Organized
            -“random file 1”
            -“random directory with files”
        -Estimates
        -Projects
        -Contracts 
    -Customer B
        -Needs Organized
            -“random file 1”
            -“random directory with files”
        -Estimates
        -Projects
        -Contracts
```

Comment: So, apparently you already know what you need to do. What have you tried to implement this, and how did it not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
:: put your dir here
cd c:\customers


for /f "delims=" %%D in ('dir /b /ad') do (
    md "%%dpfn~D\Needs Organized" >nul 2>&1
    md "%%dpfn~D\Estimates" >nul 2>&1
    md "%%dpfn~D\Projects" >nul 2>&1
    md "%%dpfn~D\Contracts" >nul 2>&1

    for /f "delims" %%F in ('dir /b /s /a-d "%%dpfn~D"') do (
        move "%%~dpfnxF" "%%dpfn~D\Needs Organized"
    )
)
```

Not tested